# Trying to import a table from Wikipedia into Google Sheets not working

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to import the table of teams at the World Cup into a Sheets file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification#Qualified_teams), but it keeps giving me an error. It says #ERROR! and when I hover over it it says:

> "Formula Parse Error".

I'm using:

```
=importHTML(“https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification#Qualified_teams”,”table”,1)
```

Comment: @pnuts, has the correct answer just confirmed your quotes are the issue. Also the function is all caps but it doesn't through an error if it is not the correct case. Just more of a visual thing.

Comment: @pnuts thanks! Can't believe the issue was so simple. Why doesn't it accept the "smart quotes" and what are they?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments the issue with the formula is actually the use of "[smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Curved_quotes_within_and_across_applications)"

A quick way to identify this issue within Google Sheets is that in the formula editor properly quoted strings are colored green.

When pasting a formula in from some other source if the quoted text does not turn green delete the quotation marks and retype them.